# Profile Login IP Range Description Missing

Tags: api, metadata-api, profile, login

I am missing the description field from the loginIpRanges for profiles. According to this doc (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_profile.htm#ProfileLoginIpRange_title) using version 31 or later should retrieve this field. However, using the Force.com Migration tool or the readMetadata() call does only returns this:

```
<loginIpRanges>
    <endAddress>xx.xx.xx.xx</endAddress>
    <startAddress>xx.xx.xx.xx</startAddress>
</loginIpRanges>
```

Any ideas or is this a known bug?

Comment: Anyone out there?

Comment: Can we insert multiple IP ranges in salesforce through PHP?

Comment: I've never had this working either - I suspect it is a bug too.

Comment: I actually had to scrape Salesforce profile webpages to get the descriptions programmatically.